# How to split a string by comma and single quotation mark in apex?

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions

Following is a string:

```
 'First Name','Last Name','Account Name','Email','Title','Description'
```

and I want it to split with `",'"` (comma and single quotation mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following code and it works fine.

```
String str = '\'First Name\',\'Last Name\',\'Account Name\',\'Email\',\'Title\',\'Description\'';

List<String> splitList = str.split(',\'');

for(String str : splitList)
    System.debug(str.replace('\'',''));
```

Comment: Dilip... this ans will give you text with single quotes..

Comment: Finally you removed the single quotes.. You are looking for only text string. Thanks for update your answer.. This is the same thing I did yesterday..

Comment: hmmm..... right.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this

First remove all single quotes and then split by comma

```
String str = '\'First Name\',\'Last Name\',\'Account Name\',\'Email\',\'Title\',\'Description\'';
System.debug('===str==='+str);
for(String strFinal: str.replace('\'', '').split(','))
{
    System.debug('===Final val==='+strFinal);
}
```

[image]

### Another option

If we are sure single quotes will be start and end of string then we can remove using string method

```
for(String strFinal: str.split(','))
{
    System.debug('===Final val==='+strFinal.removeStart('\'').removeEnd('\''));
}
```

Comment: I put minus here cause in this case expected result would be received without single quote in the end of each string (after splitting), and in case if of another string  with comma in between quote/comma sequences would create extra strings.

Comment: @kurunve yeah agree.. do you have any idea.. in that use case how we should handle?

Comment: actually, topic starter proposed one good way about how to do it -- split via `',\''`. That would give exactly that outcome that has been asked in question, and it does not have any data loss (in string). Of course, that is pretty easy to do further processing by removing extra quotes if needed. but  again -- there would be no data loss or no extra string created

Comment: @kurunve if you use `split(',\'')` then this will not give the correct output(I have tested, this contain single quotes end of string).. One more solution I have added in my answer check..

Comment: @ sfdcweb, it you test your both ways on string `"\'Test, string\',\'test, so test\''`, those would fail. There is nowhere asked to have those values with/without quotes. Just question about how to split. again, split on `',\''` would do the magic, and then, if needed, you can remove extra quotes from begin and end. Splitting just on comma would produce extra string and make wrong output

Comment: @kurunve Pls check what OP did for getting the values from string http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/117461/18731